# why cast variable to int but still print float in python3

Tags: python

why is `a` not print out to `-1` after I cast it to `int()`?

```
a = -1.0
print(a)
print(int(a))
print(a) # expect -1
```

Comment: `int` is not in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cast it to int but did not save your result. try `a = int(a)`
now `print(a)` would print `-1`

Comment: I feel so silly. It works now, thank you for your answer.